# Rest easy 3 + Jackson + Tomcat + XML response

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, jackson, resteasy

For getting json response reseasy defines a way to integrate with Jackson.
using reseasy-jackson-provider and resteasy-jackson2-provider.

Jackson can also be used to seralize deserialize from\to XML. i.e with jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider and jackson-dataformat-xml. But using these and producing XML response fails with

```
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: someclass of media type: application/xml
```

Dependencies  used

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-validator-provider-11</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Resource

```
@GET
@Path("/foo/{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Foo getFoo(@PathParam("id") int id);
```

Comment: what is the question? Can you formulate it?

Comment: question is how to get a xml response from resteasy using jackson

Comment: at present in resteady-jackson2-provider jar there is a writer interceptor called Jackson2JsonInterceptor. I feel similar one for xml is required to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

created 
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1352

lets see if it gets into resteasy artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

JAXB is the annotation framework that maps Java classes to XML and XML schema.To use JAXB in Resteasy, you need to add resteasy-jaxb-provider to your dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, add xml annotation to your response class. For example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="user") 
class User {
    int id;
    String name;      

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

UPDATE：
Since Resteasy doesn't have built-in xml provider based on Jackson, you may also write your own handlers if you don't like JAXB annotation. 
Using following dependency because `jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider` is deprecated after Jackson 2.1:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  <version>{jackson-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In you project, implement the `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter` interface.
Sample code:

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/xml")
public class XMLMarshaller implements MessageBodyWriter<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {            
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Object obj, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {            
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object obj, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
            OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException {

        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.writeValue(entityStream, obj);            
    }    
}
```

JAX-RS runtime will look at each writer’s `@Produces` annotation and call the `MessageBodyWriter.isWriteable()` method; then your custom `MessageBodyWriter` will be chosen to do the job

Comment: is there a way to achieve it without adding annotations to my model classes. with jackson it is possible and i was able to return json with resteasy. Was trying to return xml also with jackson.

Comment: @jathinsanghvi Currently Resteasy has no built-in handlers or providers that allows you to automatically convert Java object to XML(  [default_providers](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Default_Providers_and_default_JAX-RS_Content_Marshalling)). Even so, you can write your own handlers by implementing the javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter interface and Jackson xml component

Comment: ok this look simple.. will have to try it. I was thinking on implementing the com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.xml.JacksonJaxbXMLProvider. Implemeting class would be something similar to org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider. Then it could be used in a more generic context.

Comment: jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider does not seem to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to putting

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

to your POM file, **remove all JAXB (@Xml*) annotations.** JAXB annotations will trigger default provider.

Tested with Thorntail and Jackson 2.9.